# Time taken in executing % / * + - operations

Tags: time, operators

Recently, i heard that % operator is costly in terms of time.

So, the question is that, is there a way to find the remainder faster?

Also your help will be appreciated if anyone can tell the difference in the execution of % / * + - operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases where you're using power-of-2 divisors you can do better with roll-your-own techniques for calculating remainder, but generally a halfway decent compiler will do the best job possible with variable divisors, or "odd" divisors that don't fit any pattern.

Note that a few CPUs don't even have a multiply operation, and so (on those) multiply is quite slow vs add (at least 64x for a 32-bit multiply).  (But a smart compiler may improve on this if the multiplier is a literal.)  A slightly larger number do not have a divide operation or have a pretty slow one.  (On a CPU with a fast multiplier multiply may only be on the order of 4 times slower than add, but on "normal" hardware it's 16-32 times slower for a 32 bit operation.  Divide is inherently 2-4x slower than multiply, but can be much slower on some hardware.)

The remainder operation is rarely implemented in hardware, and normally `A % B` maps to something along the lines of `A - ((A / B) * B)` (a few extra operations may be required to assure the proper sign, et al).

(I learned about this stuff while microprogramming the instruction set for the [SUMC computer for RCA/NASA](http://naca.larc.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19730038993&qs=N%3D4294961259%2B4294963045%2B4294768863) back in the early 70s.)

Comment: The remainder (for `%`) is quite often output as part of the divide operation. x86 and MIPS implement this, which covers a fairly large subset of modern processors.

Comment: @nneonneo - Ah, yes, I was forgetting that.  Though several processors do not surface the remainder from a divide (as a separate result), and often the remainder obtained that way is not conformant with the language's definition.  As an aside, it's sometimes frustrating that no common language provides a *divide-with-remainder* operation, since when you need the remainder you often need the quotient.  (Though I suppose some compilers can optimize the two operations together in the right circumstances.)

Comment: Python is common, and it has `divmod` for exactly that purpose :)

Comment: @nneonneo - I'm guessing that there are some Python users who would take offense at your calling it "common'. ;)

Comment: Well, you said "no common language". Python is commonly used. Therefore it is commonplace.

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiler is going to implement % in the most efficient way possible.

In terms of speed, + and - are the fastest (and are equally fast, generally done by the same hardware).

*, /, and % are much slower.  Multiplication is basically done by the method you learn in grade school-  multiply the first number by every digit in the second number and add the results.  With some hacks made possible by binary.  As of a few years ago, multiply was 3x slower than add.  Division should be similar to multiply.  Remainder is similar to division (in fact it generally calculates both at once).

Exact differences depend on the CPU type and exact model.  You'd need to look up the latencies in the CPU spec sheets for your particular machine.

Comment: Is there any source i can get more information from? Maybe i am missing to ask something.

Comment: Best way to learn this-  learn assembly and digital circuit design.  As a bonus you'll learn how your computer really works and how things are done under the hood.